# How to read two-dimensional complex data with pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, complex-numbers

1） I have a data format like this, it is read by np.fromfile(path_file,dtype=np.complex64)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKw8w.png)
2）Its data format is named with a raw suffix, which I previously wrote via python's write(path,'wb')

I am passing the data into hdfs, how can I read the data through a kind of rdd, I have used binaryfile to read the data, but the data read out is garbled, please ask how I can read out the data for the kind of format in the figure?

1)sc.binaryfile:It reads out a garbled code
2)sc.textfile:Read out as a string

dataset = np.array([[-1+1j,-1+1j,-1+1j],[-2+2j,-2+2j,-2+2j],[-3+3j,-3+3j,-3+3j],[-4+4j,-4+4j,-4+4j]])
Since there is too much content in the dataset, I approximate my dataset with a 4×3 matrix, which is created with np.array

Comment: Please provide your dataset in text tabular format. It is difficult to reproduce the problem with image. Refer [this formatting help guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)

Comment: Since the dataset is so large, I approximated my dataset with a 4×3 matrix that was created using np.array. I have re-added this to my question and look forward to your response @AzharKhan